# I cannot get iptables to show trace logs

Tags: debian, iptables

```
uname -a
Linux test 5.10.0-17-cloud-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.136-1 (2022-08-13) x86_64 GNU/Linux

# enable logging
sudo modprobe ipt_LOG
sudo modprobe nf_log_ipv4
sudo sysctl net.netfilter.nf_log.2=nf_log_ipv4

# Try to log traffic
sudo iptables -t raw -I PREROUTING -s 1.2.3.4 -j LOG
sudo iptables -t raw -I PREROUTING -s 1.2.3.5 -j LOG
# I see logs for these IPs
tail /var/log/kern.log

# Try to trace traffic
sudo iptables -t raw -I PREROUTING -s 1.2.3.4 -j TRACE
sudo iptables -t raw -I PREROUTING -s 1.2.3.5 -j TRACE
# See no trace logs for these IPs
tail /var/log/kern.log
```

I see LOGs in log file but I see zero trace logs. I can't find info anywhere on why this might be.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Debian [switched](https://wiki.debian.org/nftables#Current_status) to *iptables*-over-*nftables* with Debian 10, so this includes Debian 11.

```
$ update-alternatives --list iptables
/usr/sbin/iptables-legacy
/usr/sbin/iptables-nft
$ update-alternatives --display iptables
iptables - auto mode
  link best version is /usr/sbin/iptables-nft
  link currently points to /usr/sbin/iptables-nft
  link iptables is /usr/sbin/iptables
[...]
```

The `TRACE` target framework is specifically different with this variant, to benefit from the advantages of the *nftables* API. It's described in the manuals for the [iptables `TRACE` target](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8#TRACE) and [`xtables-monitor`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/xtables-monitor.8):

> With iptables-nft, the target is translated into nftables'
> `meta nftrace` expression. Hence the kernel sends trace events via netlink to
> userspace where they may be displayed using `xtables-monitor --trace`
> command. For details, refer to [xtables-monitor(8)](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/xtables-monitor.8).

> `xtables-monitor` is used to monitor changes to the ruleset or to **show
> rule evaluation events for packets tagged using the TRACE target**.
> `xtables-monitor` will run until the user aborts execution, typically by
> using CTRL-C.

That means a lot of documentation and many blogs are becoming stale and showing only the legacy method.

Now with `iptables-nft`, one can just run this to display traces:

```
xtables-monitor -t
```

---

Here's at least one advantage with the new API:

Older API (still present when using the command `iptables-legacy`) sent TRACE results to the kernel ring buffer (eg: using `dmesg`). This buffer is not network-namespace aware, so there's the choice of logging only the initial network namespace activity (which includes the TRACE results), or all network namespaces activity with a toggle. TRACE being very verbose, this would quickly be a problem.

The new API uses [netlink](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages/netlink.7) multicast-like socket messages to provide information to possibly multiple listener(s). It is also network-namespace aware. It doesn't pollute logs. Implementers chose to break compabitility for this specific target used only when debugging, to leverage *nftables*' API instead of keeping the original behavior.

That means when running multiple network namespace, one can trace them separately (as long as they have rules with TRACE targets) for example like this:

```
ip netns exec othernamespace xtables-monitor -t
```

with complete isolation from all other network namespaces.

The *nftables* command `nft monitor trace` would mostly work as well (maybe not displaying native xtables matches and targets) instead of `xtables-monitor -t` to monitor these *iptables* rules since it's the same API.

---

Actually, using the `NFLOG` target instead of `LOG` has a similar behavior (and is identical using the legacy or the nft API) and sends logs using the same kind of facility, for specialized logging tools: usually [`ulogd`](https://manpages.debian.org/ulogd2/ulogd.8) but even `tcpdump` is able to capture it on Linux. Example:

terminal 1:

```
$ ping 127.0.0.1
[...]
```

terminal 2 (as root):

```
# iptables -I INPUT -i lo -p icmp -j NFLOG --nflog-group 123
# tcpdump -ttttt -n -l -i nflog:123
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on nflog:123, link-type NFLOG (Linux netfilter log messages), snapshot length 262144 bytes
 00:00:00.000000 IP 127.0.0.1 > 127.0.0.1: ICMP echo request, id 47883, seq 36, length 64
 00:00:00.000399 IP 127.0.0.1 > 127.0.0.1: ICMP echo reply, id 47883, seq 36, length 64
 00:00:01.023906 IP 127.0.0.1 > 127.0.0.1: ICMP echo request, id 47883, seq 37, length 64
 00:00:01.023976 IP 127.0.0.1 > 127.0.0.1: ICMP echo reply, id 47883, seq 37, length 64
^C
4 packets captured
4 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

additional information: [NFLOG with wireshark](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/NFLOG.md), [Nftables and the Netfilter logging framework](https://home.regit.org/2014/02/nftables-and-netfilter-logging-framework/).

Comment: What an amazing answer. I was going to link back to this answer from this related SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63791460/debian-buster-10-iptables-raw-trace-no-logs. But you should really copy pasta this answer there so you get credit.