Can I masquerade traffic coming over a veth pair without a bridge?
Appologies for the cross-post from superuser but I think this belongs here...
I have created a veth pair with one end of the pair in a net namespace. I assigned the address 10.1.2.50/24 to the side of the pair that is within the namespace, and 10.1.2.1/24 to the side that is in the root namespace. I set up an iptables rule to masquerade traffic from the subnet associated with the veth pair with:
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.1.2.0/24 ! -o my-veth -j MASQUERADE

Does this sound sensible? Can I masquerade traffic coming over a veth pair without creating a bridge?
From outside the namespace I can ping 10.1.2.50 and from within the namespace, I can ping both 10.1.2.1 and also the host's public IP. But from within the namespace I cannot ping public IPs on the internet (it hangs forever waiting for a response). How might I debug?
My setup is as follows. I created the pair like this:
ip link add my-veth type veth peer name my-ceth

I put one end of the pair in a namespace:
ip link set my-ceth netns my-ns

I assigned IP addresses inside and outside the namespace:
ip addr add 10.1.2.1/24 dev my-veth
nsenter --net=/run/netns/my-ns ip addr add 10.1.2.50/24 dev my-ceth

I brought up the devices inside and outside the namespace:
ip link set my-veth up
nsenter --net=/run/netns/my-ns ip link set my-ceth up

I set a default route within the namespace:
nsenter --net=/run/netns/my-ns ip route add default via 10.1.2.1

I created an iptables rule outside the namespace to NAT traffic from the namespace:
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.1.2.0/24 ! -o my-veth -j MASQUERADE

My ip addr looks like this:
133: my-veth@if132: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f6:b9:cb:fe:44:4a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netns my-ns
    inet 10.1.2.1/24 scope global my-veth
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::f4b9:cbff:fefe:444a/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

And inside the namespace:
132: my-ceth@if133: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e2:c6:18:68:c8:14 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 10.1.2.50/24 scope global my-ceth
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

My ip route looks like this:
default via 192.168.88.1 dev wlo1 proto dhcp metric 600 
10.1.2.0/24 dev my-veth proto kernel scope link src 10.1.2.1 

And inside the namespace:
default via 10.1.2.1 dev my-ceth 
10.1.2.0/24 dev my-ceth proto kernel scope link src 10.1.2.50 

And my iptables -t nat --list-rules outside the namespace looks like this:
-P PREROUTING ACCEPT
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-P POSTROUTING ACCEPT
-N DOCKER
-A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A OUTPUT ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.1.2.0/24 ! -o my-veth -j MASQUERADE
-A DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN

Yet I cannot ping public IPs from inside the namespace:
$ sudo ip netns exec my-ns ping 93.184.215.14
PING 93.184.215.14 (93.184.215.14) 56(84) bytes of data.

Any help much appreciated!

You should really check the filtering part (for "forward" traffics) of the firewalls (iptables and nftables).

That all looks broadly correct. I've condensed your steps into the following script, where I've made a couple of changes that shouldn't impact things operationally:

I've replaced your use of nsenter with the simpler alternative of either ip -n <namespace> where appropriate, or ip netns exec.
I combined the "create veth peer" step and the "add one end of the pair to a network namespace" step into a single step using the netns option to ip link add.
I added a LOG rule before the MASQUERADE rule just to see matching traffic in the kernel log.

#!/bin/bash

set -e

# make sure we haven't already run this script
if ip netns exec my-ns true > /dev/null 2>&1; then
  echo "ERROR: namespace already exists" >&2
  exit 1
fi

ip netns add my-ns

ip link add my-veth type veth peer name my-ceth netns my-ns

ip addr add 10.1.2.1/24 dev my-veth
ip link set my-veth up

ip -n my-ns addr add 10.1.2.50/24 dev my-ceth
ip -n my-ns link set my-ceth up
ip -n my-ns route add default via 10.1.2.1

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.1.2.0/24 -j LOG
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.1.2.0/24 ! -o my-veth -j MASQUERADE

After running this script, I can ping external addresses from the network namespace:
# ip netns exec my-ns ping -c1 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=16.9 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 16.853/16.853/16.853/0.000 ms


@larsks This is helpful and generous. Thank you for the pointers related to the use of the ip command. The iptables log line is especially helpful to me. I'm going to try doing the same on a VM with a base install of ubuntu. My guess now is that my problem is some kind of conflict with the iptables rules that docker has installed on my system.

@AlexFlint you can look into enabling tracing to identify which rules are matching your traffic. How to do that depends on whether you are using legacy iptables or iptables-nft (or just nft directly).

Hey @larsks, thanks - I'm using iptables-nft: iptables v1.8.7 (nf_tables)

Then you should be able to iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING ... -j TRACE to enable tracing (where you replace ... with appropriate matches), and nft monitor trace to see the trace logs. At least, that's what works on my system. https://serverfault.com/questions/1109845/i-cannot-get-iptables-to-show-trace-logs has some additional thoughts on the topic.
